# Macro unable to finish, is my sheet too big?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to run what I thought was a simple macro for two days and keep running into this error:

"Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other applications."

I would love to get 20,000 iterations out of the macro but the error shows up way sooner than that.  I think it stops around 5,000.  Even worse is that I can't save what I do get afterward.  I know there is a somewhat large amount of data after that many iterations but nowhere near filling an entire sheet.  I would like to be able to run the macro and then optimize the weights out to the right.

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To 20000

        Rows("16:28").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(2, -3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Selection.Resize(13, 288).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
        End If

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Sample data:

[image]

Sorry, I forgot to post a link to the workbook:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0F1yWDNKi2vLWhmUDMtU2xsd00

Comment: You're right, 20,000 iterations shouldn't be too much on VBA, however the information you provided isn't enough to identify the problem; there can be several reasons: 1: Resources are really low, close some applications, 2: Try to disable calculations during the run of your macro, 3: You may need to optimize your code (as I haven't seen it I can't help now but big arrays or recursion are likely problems). Also have a look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2779852

Comment: That is not a public link. Bad user.

Comment: Sorry, link should be public now

Answer (score 1):

Based on Pauls description of what your code does, this may work for you, it did for my own test data:

```
Sub Quickcopy()
Rows(29).Insert 'Make sure there is a blank row there
With Range("A30:D" & 280000) '280000 = 14 rows multiplied by your number of copies. Change D to however far the columns go
    .Formula = "=IF(A16="""","""",A16)" 'Had to do this otherwise a straight =A16 returned 0 where blanks exist. Note Excel is smart enough to increment the row ref as it goes
    .Copy 'Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste values
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very nice ! (I just saw it now). For columns A:D it works well (and fast), but it needs to copy columns A to PG; I made the change and it also ran out of memory with the same message, but this is a +1 for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Your code copies all data from row 16 to 28, for 20,000 times, with and empty row between sets.

This code performs the same operation (in about 1 minute):

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyData()
    Const F_ROW     As Long = 16
    Const F_COL     As Long = 3
    Const SEP       As Long = 2
    Const COPIES    As Long = 20000

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, t As Double, allR As Long
    Dim srcRng As Variant, lr As Long, lc As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, F_COL + 1).End(xlUp).Row           'last row of data
        lc = .Cells(F_ROW + 1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last col of data

        allR = lr - F_ROW
        srcRng = .Range(.Cells(F_ROW, F_COL), .Cells(lr, lc)).Formula

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        For i = 1 To COPIES
            .Range(.Cells(lr + SEP, F_COL), .Cells(lr + allR + SEP, lc)).Formula = srcRng
            lr = lr + allR + SEP
        Next
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        .Calculate
        .Cells(1, 1).Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

.

Notes:

- It generates 280,028 rows with 423 columns so you should save it as .xlsb:

  - .xlsm: file size 772 Mb - 5 min to save, 3 min to open
  - .xlsb: file size 475 Mb - 1 min to save, 1 min to open

.

**Edit:**

I changed the code to copy **`.Formula`** instead of `.Value2` and ran into the same issue:

- Excel runs out of memory when i = 1,276 (completed rows: 17,882)
- 13 rows X 421 columns = 5,473 cells, with a total of 4,979 formulas
- Task Mgr: Excel.exe - Memory (Private Working Set): 1,833,524 Kb (out of memory)
- `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` doesn't solve the problem
- I also tried to run the code for 1,000 iterations, then manually copy and paste 20 more times

  - It ran out of memory ("Excel cannot complete this task with available resources...")
- Last attempt was in Notepad++ to exclude calculations from the process

  - In Excel: Formulas -> Show Formulas (in Formula Auditing section), then copy
  - In Notepad: paste formulas
  - Copy lines 16 to 28 + a blank row
  - Pasted the rows several times but eventually Notepad ran out of memory as well

Comment: This code is very interesting but I am not sure that it does exactly what mine does.  In your code, each block of cells (the area between the blank lines) is the same and all cells are hard coded.  I only hard coded the values in the first 288 columns and only did that after the values in the first 288 columns changed.  I would be happy to leave the formulas in the first 288 columns but I thought that was the source of the slowness.  In any case, each block of cells should be different.

Comment: I'll examine your code more closely but it would be helpful if you can explain what it is supposed to do (what blocks of cells you want to copy, and in what pattern)

Comment: Good idea.  Everything in rows 16 through 28 needs to be replicated 20,000 times.  Most of the cells in rows 16 through 28 are formulas.  They are all keyed off columns C through L; these are random numbers generated by the rand() function.  In my original macro, each time C through L are pasted, the rand() function is recalculated and this results in a unique set of values.  The reason I added a paste-special-values to my macro is that I thought that once the unique set of values were calculated, the macro would run faster if as many values in the sheet were hard coded as possible.

Comment: I made adjustments to copy formulas instead of values and it generated the same error (see my edit)